# need to hold execution of my app until my firebase upload function returns download url

Tags: angular

i have user registration form in which user need to upload document.zip file and i store all the data to firebase. 
the problem is when upload function is called angular does not wait for the function to generate download url and resume the execution further which generate the error that download url is undefine. how to solve these.

p.s: sorry for my english.

```
 async getDownloadURL(){
    console.log('get download ult function called');
    await this.storage.upload('/adopt/' + this.fullName.concat('_' + this.file.name), this.file).then(rst => {
      rst.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        console.log("File Uploaded Successfully");
        this.downloadURL = url;
        console.log(this.downloadURL);
      })
    })

this is what i have wrote to upload file and generate url

public onAdoptFormSubmit = (f: NgForm) => {

    console.log('form submit function called');
    this.getDownloadURL();
    console.log('push method start');


    this.db.list('/adopt').push({
      fullName: this.fullName,
      dob: this.dob.getTime(),
      address: this.address,
      email: this.email,
      phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
      guardianFullName: this.guardianFullName,
      guardianPhoneNumber: this.guardianPhoneNumber,
      guardianAddress: this.guardianAddress,
      sportPursue: this.sportPursue,
      achievements: this.achievements,
      schoolName: this.schoolName,
      familyIncome: this.familyIncome,
      goals: this.goals,
      whyDeserve: this.whyDeserve,
      partOfClub: this.partOfClub,
      coachName: this.coachName,
      downloadURL: this.downloadURL
    });
    this.db.list('/adopt').snapshotChanges().subscribe();
    f.reset();
    this.toastr.success('Thank you for your interest, we will get back to you shortly!');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);    

  }

  async getDownloadURL(){
    console.log('get download ult function called');
    await this.storage.upload('/adopt/' + this.fullName.concat('_' + this.file.name), this.file).then(rst => {
      rst.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        console.log("File Uploaded Successfully");
        this.downloadURL = url;
        console.log(this.downloadURL);
      })
    })
  }
```

full code which store the data to firebase

error in conosle

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make `onAdoptFormSubmit` function `async`
here is the example.

```
getDownloadURL(){
return new Promise(resolve => { 
    console.log('get download ult function called');
    this.storage.upload('/adopt/' + this.fullName.concat('_' + this.file.name), 
    this.file).then(rst => {
      rst.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        console.log("File Uploaded Successfully");
        this.downloadURL = url;
        console.log(this.downloadURL);
        resolve(); // here you can see that we resolve after getting the URL
      })
    })
 })
}

async onAdoptFormSubmit = (f: NgForm) => {

    console.log('form submit function called');

    await this.getDownloadURL(); // Our await method

    console.log('push method start');

    this.db.list('/adopt').push({
      fullName: this.fullName,
      dob: this.dob.getTime(),
      address: this.address,
      email: this.email,
      phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
      guardianFullName: this.guardianFullName,
      guardianPhoneNumber: this.guardianPhoneNumber,
      guardianAddress: this.guardianAddress,
      sportPursue: this.sportPursue,
      achievements: this.achievements,
      schoolName: this.schoolName,
      familyIncome: this.familyIncome,
      goals: this.goals,
      whyDeserve: this.whyDeserve,
      partOfClub: this.partOfClub,
      coachName: this.coachName,
      downloadURL: this.downloadURL
    });
    this.db.list('/adopt').snapshotChanges().subscribe();
    f.reset();
    this.toastr.success('Thank you for your interest, we will get back to you shortly!');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);    

  }

getDownloadURL(){
    console.log('get download ult function called');
    this.storage.upload('/adopt/' + this.fullName.concat('_' + this.file.name), this.file).then(rst => {
      rst.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        console.log("File Uploaded Successfully");
        this.downloadURL = url;
        console.log(this.downloadURL);
      })
    })
  }
```

Let me know if it is works or not.